# understanding kinetic friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I have a pen on my table.

I apply force horizontally to my pen. The force I apply is stronger then the maximum static friction so it moves.

I move the pen at constant velocity.

Now if we look physically, then $F_k$ must be equal to the force I apply (Second Law of Newton).

The magnitude of $F_k$ is constant according to $\mu_kmg$ where $m$ is mass of my pen.

However I can also move my pen at constant velocity with greater or smaller force.

How it is possible? I don't get it, if the magnitude of $F_k$ is constant and I apply force smaller or greater then the force I had with first constant velocity, we must have acceleration.

But we don't have constant acceleration. Or my eyes are not precise enough?

Comment: In reality the force is usually not constant but velocity dependent, we simply have to ignore that in high school physics because the students don't know enough about differential equations to analyze the dynamics resulting from velocity dependent forces. For the case where the friction force is constant the pen would accelerate if it was exceeded by the applied force. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I understand the last thing you said, nothing wrong with that.
I just don't see it happening in the real world as you said.
If you assume we have more kinetic friction with growing velocity then it might be fine that we have constant velocity with different forces applied.
However I can imagine my pen moving at constant 50 km/h  with certain force. And constant 1 cm/s with another force.  It just seems odd to me. @CuriousOne

Comment: That's exactly what happens in the real world for a scenario in which the force is independent of the velocity, but, like I said, that scenario is not so easy to find. Friction (the real deal) is a difficult phenomenon and the school version of it is oversimplified to absurdity for the sake of teaching. One could potentially teach linear velocity dependent friction, but discussing the physically more common and more relevant quadratic velocity dependence of e.g. aerodynamic friction is already out of the question.

Comment: Now, if we take @user2197013's answer seriously, then you may be mistaking the power to perform the motion for the force and then you are making a major , also correct, observation. Since $W=Fds$, $P=dW/dt=Fds/dt=Fv$, i.e. the power needed to move a body against a constant friction force is proportional to the velocity, so it feels harder to pull something at a higher velocity against a constant force, even if the force doesn't change. The human body will, of course, sense both the force and the power that is needed to perform a task, so the sensation may be somewhat misleading.

Comment: Ok, I get it, although my main question was about the constant velocity.
How are you writing equations in here?
Like you did in the last comment.
@CuriousOne

Comment: You mean MathJax? I think this is the official intro page for the stackexchange sites: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. I usually look up the syntax there. :-) Isn't that what you did in your post? Same syntax applies in comments, I think. It doesn't seem to work in the chat rooms.

Comment: Have you done any measurements of the force applied and the speed or acceleration which results?  If not, you are asking us to explain your subjective observation, your perception, not a physical fact.

Answer (score 2):

When you move the pen at constant velocity, you are correct that you apply $F=\mu_kmg$. This is true regardless of what constant velocity you choose. The difference is you have to supply more force initially to accelerate the pen to a faster speed, but once it is up to speed you only need $\mu_kmg$ to keep it at that speed.

So it really isn't the force that is changing. You may feel like you are putting more effort in, but that can be do to a variety of effects. First, it could be that the coefficient of friction depends on velocity to some degree in this case (not sure how common that is for table surfaces, but it certainly occurs in air resistance). It could also be that you applied more force initially when accelerating the pen to the speed you want, but not once it is up to speed.

Comment: I believe the OP is only talking about force, not about effort. It is undoubtedly true that he can move the pen with the same force at a higher velocity while expending more power, but that doesn't seem to be his question. Unless, of course, your take on it is that the OP doesn't know the difference between force and power?

Comment: My take on it is that he was not quite right in suggesting he can do it with a different amount of force. But yes, perhaps I read it a little wrong. I was thinking he mistook higher speed/power for more force.